# Replace android string resource values with a Gradle Task with resValue() or something similar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

I'm looking into changing string resource values with a Gradle Task.  I'm looking at most likely using a Copy Task, to copy string.xml and overwrite.

At this point I think I'm going to be rewriting the contents of the xml file and replacing using a regex pattern.  This seems like a bad way to do this, isnt there a better way to use something like `resValue()` within a Gradle Task?

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to achieve with this specifically ? sounds like an interesting situation

Comment: white labeling.. my application has a few strings i pull from other sources that aren't local, so i have to download them and then replace

Comment: ahh i see, goodluck though, hopefully you do get a cool answer

Answer (score 1):

I see three ways to do this, details will depend on your exact setup, so I will just point at things that may help you:

1) We do the copying via `type: Copy` too in some cases. The way we go about it is to have the possible versions of the files that are variable stored in specific subfolders which are excluded from building. Then we copy the version required by a specific build into source, where the build process depends on the copy tasks which ensures the correct file is available before compilation.

2) You can look into `gradle.properties`. This is where you can store key-value-pairs to be available to gradle and managing your build pipeline. You can define properties like this:

```
someProperty=abc123
```

This is then loaded in Gradle via `${someProperty}` **during configuration stage**.

3) For your various builds you can introduce different build pipelines. This is not distinct from 1), 2), but you can use this to control which config you use. You can for example use configuration tasks to set `gradle.properties` and let Gradle execute a specific build pipeline using a specific `settings.xml` depending on the values in `gradle.properties`. Or you can just define tasks for each possible `settings.xml` and then execute these.

If there are more efficient ways to achieve this, then I am also interested in the answer. Hope any of this helps.